# fail to connect tomcat 7 webpage in Linux Oracle 6.3

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7, nolio

I installed a server which has already embedded tomcat 7. 
I fail to access the server's webpage when the server is running.
What i need is to access the administration page ie. http://xxx.xxx.xx.77:8080/Nolio-app

then i got The errors below.
Please Help & Thank you!!

For more information:
the server use mysql, which require mysql-connect-java-5.1.21.jar
But i can only find mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar available from internet

The server using following setting.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /data/Nolio-4.7

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /data/Nolio-4.7

Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /data/Nolio-4.7/temp

Using JRE_HOME:        ./jre

Using CLASSPATH:       /data/Nolio-4.7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/data/Nolio-4.7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Using CATALINA_PID:    ./catalina.pid

---

```
Aug 20, 2013 6:04:43 AM org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore open
SEVERE: JDBC driver class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

---

```
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:08 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:08 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1898 ms
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.14
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive nexus.war
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Manager} Setting property 'minIdelSwap' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Configuring Nexus in vanilla WAR...
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Setting Plexus basedir context variable to (discovered from Servlet container): /data/Nolio-4.7/webapps/nexus/WEB-INF
Aug 20, 2013 8:55:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.open(JDBCStore.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.getConnection(JDBCStore.java:844)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.startInternal(JDBCStore.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.startInternal(PersistentManagerBase.java:824)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)

Aug 20, 2013 8:55:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/nexus] startup failed due to previous errors
....
```

---

Comment: Kindly check the following link to get the 5.1.21 jar. Check if that solves your problem. http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-connector-java-5.1&o=other

Comment: is it the same if i use mysql-connect-java or mysql-connector-java?

Comment: Yes. Although latest versions of `JAR` are more preferred as they add  bug fixes.Are you sure you've added the JAR in your classpath.. ?

Comment: i have tried to add the classpath to the programme, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Alright. Try adding the 5.1.21.jar directly to the /data/Nolio-4.7/bin folder. See if that works.

Comment: it works for the nolio installed in windows, but not works for linux

Comment: Are you using any IDE for Linux.. ?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help:) 
The Linux system is ghost image from my company. Some setting has been modified. And noting are installed but the nolio.

Comment: No problems mate.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the latest Nolio versions doesn't support Mysql out of the box, and require some configuration for it. This is the Nolio knowledge base, on how to configure version 4.7 to work with Mysql - 
[Nolio 4.7 - Custom Installation without Database Configuration](https://communities.ca.com/thread/110334475) This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception while trying to configure the **PersistentManager** with a JDBC Store using MySQL. I just had to copy the mysql-connector jar (for instance *mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar*) to my tomcat library directory (*[tomcatDir]/lib/.*)

If the connection string is incorrect you get another error:

```
org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore getConnection
SEVERE: A SQL exception occurred com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'invalidDB'
```